# Forever-monitor throwing ENOENT and not working

Tags: node.js, express, forever

so I have:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');
var Monitor = forever.Monitor;

var child = new Monitor('clusters.js', {
  max: 10,
  silent: false,
  killTree: true,
  logFile: './logs/forever.log',
  outFile: './logs/app.log',
  errFile: './logs/error.log'
});

child.on('exit', function (err) {
  console.log('Server exitted');
});

child.start();
```

and it always throw the same error: events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event with:

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Does anyone know what is going on and how to fix it?
Im on Windows 7 with:

```
"express": "3.3.5",
"forever-monitor": "~1.2.2"
```

Comment: looks like `spawn` is being called for a command that isn't a command. Should that be "node clusters.js" instead of "clusters.js"?

Comment: no, I tried and its not the problem.

Comment: @VitorHugo Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @mattblang "resolved" it by downgrading forever-monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/blai/grunt-express/issues/12

Apparently the problem is with forever-monitor 1.2, I downgraded to 1.1 and it just worked.
From what I got there they dont seem to be doing anything about it either...